# .Net Core Web API Bearer The issuer is invalid

Tags: jwt, identityserver4, blazor, webapi

I have written a Blazor WASM app based on the latest Microsoft template. In development mode it all works great but after publishing it to Azure App Service I randomly get a 401 unauthorised when calling the API, looking at the returned headers I get

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer 'https://*domain*.azurewebsites.net' is invalid"
```

This is when the client is using the https://*domain*.azurewebsites.net client. So it matches the web API.

I also have a custom domain attached to the app service, this means there is also  https://www.*domain*.co.uk and https://*domain*.co.uk both are SSL'd.

I have checked the JWT token and it contains the correct URL for the version of the website I am calling.

Sometimes everything works but 60% of the time it allows the user to login and then fails on the API calls. I can't seem to track it to 1 domain name or pattern like expired logins. If you log out and then log back in, it doesn't clear the issue.

The configure looks like this

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });
    }
```

Any help or hints in the right direction is appreciated

Cheers

Dave

Comment: did you figure this out dave, I have the same issue with IS4 running in azure web app for containers (linux)

Comment: Hi J King, Nope never got to the bottom of this, I ended up creating a Web App per URL and minimising to 1 URL per Web App. This worked but is not a great solution

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by Linux environment of App Service. Now documentation has a clear note on that:
`For Azure App Service deployments on Linux, specify the issuer explicitly in Startup.ConfigureServices`.

This is how I set it:

```
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(
  IdentityServerJwtConstants.IdentityServerJwtBearerScheme, 
  options =>
  {
    options.Authority = "https://my-site.azurewebsites.net";
#if DEBUG
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
#endif
  });
```